# Adding JBoss AS 7 libs as Gradle Dependency

Tags: java, jboss7.x, gradle, dependency-management

I need to add JBoss 7.1.1 libs as a [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) dependency in my project, because I need them in compile time.

But all the dependencies I have are added from a Maven Repo.

I have seen **how** to do it, I can add them as a `providedCompile` dependency, using [this](http://blog.codeaholics.org/2012/emulating-mavens-provided-scope-in-gradle/) technique right here. But what do I associate it to?

How do I add libs that I have in my JBoss Modules as a Gradle dependency?

---

**EDIT**

I have seen I can add a file tree to my dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'myDir', include: '*.jar')
}
```

But it doesn't work recursively. It only adds the defined folder,
and  JBoss AS 7.1.1 has all the `jars` splitted in modules, is there any way I can reference the entire module folder, instead of each specific one?

What I **want** to do is somehting like this, but it **doesn't** work with this syntax:

```
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: '%JBOSS_HOME%/modules', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'myDir', include: '**/*.jar')
}
```

This should add all .jar files in all subfolders of 'myDir'.

Explanation: The `**/` before the `*.jar` tells it to recursively check all directories for the .jar files.