# How to recursively add a list of Jars to your classpath in gradle with groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I have a hierarchical directory of jars that I am looking to add to my buildscripts classpath. I have written a task that compiles all the jars into a list, however I am at a loss when trying to apply them to the classpath.  Has anyone encountered this before?  Any help would be much appreciate.

The snippet of my code follows:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

buildscript {

    repositories {

    }

    dependencies {

    }
}

task classpaths << {

    def list = []
    def dir = new File("/usr/local/foo/bar/packages")
    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file->
        if (file.isFile() && file.name.endsWith("jar")) {
            list << file
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Think http://stackoverflow.com/a/23897638/6509 covers your issue

Comment: @tim_yates
That actually doesn't answer my question as I wanted to reecursively access all files in the directory.  I actually just found the answer.
    `dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'foobar', include: '**/*.jar')
    }`

Comment: Sorry, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16285120/6509 then instead